# cake php good looking url routing

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a PostController with URL: http://cakephp.local/posts/view/20
Now, I'd like to rewrite it to, such as: http://cakephp.local/posts/view/some_text_contents.html

with: some_text_contents is title field of Post Model (in table post).

So, what must I do? 
Anyone has experience with this, please give me a help. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function view($title) {
    $this->Post->title = $title;
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
}
```

This will return you:
cakephp.local/posts/view/some_text_contents

with this rewrite .htaccess file with following way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! \.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: how if I just want the rewrited URL is http://cakephp.local/posts/some_text_contents.html

Comment: edit your htacess file, if you get help from my answer then give me up vote and accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite URL like this you need to pass the title as parameter of view method (like hizbul25 did), not the record ID.

See this thread: [CakePHP: Use post title as the slug for view method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033710/cakephp-use-post-title-as-the-slug-for-view-method)

I recommend to use a field named slug, for example, to save the title without spaces, accents and special characters, and use it as unique key on database.

Comment: This is the correct approach, `$title` may contain invalid characters, spaces, and so on which will all result in the query failing if an exact match isn't found. Using a slug also allows you to easily change the title without worrying about previously indexed links.