# How to add slug in URL according to SEO Prospective in Cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, routes

Hello i have a problem related to url in cakephp website for example my current url is `http://example.com/categories/1` when i click on any category it opens up with id.But now i want to change structure of my url like `http://example.com/abc` where abc is my category name,i have lots of category so anyone suggest me how to achieve this structure in cakephp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cakephp url modification: remove action and add slug inflector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990279/cakephp-url-modification-remove-action-and-add-slug-inflector)

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre is any other way i do it,without using slug.

Comment: You want to add slug without using slug ? I'm a bit confused here ;)

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre sir can you please elaborate your answer i just want url change as in my question